# Maven BOM for solving dependencies on Spring + Spring Data + Spring Security?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, spring-data, maven-bom

[Spring Data Jpa Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies) suggest to use Maven BOM ([bill of materials](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)) due to:

> Due to different inception dates of individual Spring Data modules, most
> of them carry different major and minor version numbers. The easiest way
> to find compatible ones is by relying on the Spring Data Release Train BOM
> we ship with the compatible versions defined. In a Maven project you’d
> declare this dependency in the `<dependencyManagement/>` section of your POM

Reference to [official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/bom/pom.xml) is provided.

I've got the idea of BOM and `dependencyManagement`. Vendor officially supply us (developers) with tested/recommended/supported compatibility list. *That is great!*

In order to move versions synchronously I need some "super-BOM" that governs following BOMs:

```
org.springframework:spring-framework-bom
org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain
org.springframework.security:spring-security-bom
```

How do I choose compatible ones?

Are there **SPRING-SUPER-BOM** for all umbrella (I mean official or community supported so I save my time by avoiding troubleshooting and if that happen and I have found and have resolved issue - I have an option to get back solution to community)?

Comment: Have you checked [the website](http://platform.spring.io/platform/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NEW** Thanks for pointing about Spring Platform deprecation to *@jumping_monkey*.

Now you should relay on [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies). It doesn't mean you started to use Spring Boot. It only means that you are using dependency management hosted by Spring Boot!

So your build file can look like:

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:${projSpringBootVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:${projSpringCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${projSpringGcpVersion}"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions = false
}
```

Note that there is still uncertainty between version of `spring-boot-starter-parent` & `spring-cloud-starter-parent`. But it is OK. At least they help to manage versions of Hibernate/Jeckson/whatever!

**OLD** Thanks to *@M.Deinum* for pointing to [Spring IO platform](https://spring.io/projects/platform)

This project provides versions of the various Spring projects and their dependencies.

Actual dependencies can be examined in corresponding http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/ or from https://github.com/spring-io/platform/blob/master/platform-bom/pom.xml file by viewing at different tags: https://github.com/spring-io/platform/tags

This is easy to do with local Git clone:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/spring-io/platform.git
$ cd platform/
$ git tag --list
$ git co v1.0.2.RELEASE
$ less platform-bom/pom.xml
```

But you didn't find here dependencies for `spring-core`/`spring-mvc`/`string-data`/`spring-security` because they are in parent pom `spring-boot-starter-parent` which actually also include `spring-boot-dependencies`.

`spring-boot-dependencies` have version and dependency to

- `spring-framework-bom`
- `spring-data-releasetrain`
- `spring-security-bom`
- `spring-integration-bom`

So if your aplication is very reach - you may use `io.spring.platform:platform-bom`. But if that over-complicated list just use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies` as `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: A bom only gives you dependency management (well and some plugins when used as parent). So which to use doesn't actually matter... I would suggest using the platform one.

Comment: I understand *dependencies on libraries* but miss what is *platform using*. Are there some plug-ins/utilities that help with coding or simplify build process? Or some IDE? Note that I just regular developer without *senior* title, so ask silly question...

Comment: I suggest a read of the reference guide as that explains those things.

Comment: For posterity, all the links in the answer are EOL, [spring-io/platform](https://github.com/spring-io/platform) has been archived. `Users of the Platform are encouraged to start using Spring Boot's dependency management directly, either by using spring-boot-starter-parent as their Maven project's parent, or by importing the spring-boot-dependencies bom.`